# Config parameter to kill spark job if it cannot get yarn containers

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

Is there a spark config parameter we can pass while submitting jobs through spark-submit, that will kill/fail job if it does not gets containers in given time?
For example if job requested for 8 yarn containers, which could not be allocated for 2 hours, then the job kill itself.

EDIT: We have scripts launching spark or MR jobs on a cluster. This issue is not a major one for MR jobs as they can start even if 1 container is available. Also MR jobs need much less memory so their containers can be smaller, hence more containers are available in cluster.